# python: separate out rows which have duplicates in panda dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

Suppose a data frame `df` has three columns `c1, c2, c3`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['c1']=[1,2,3,3,4]
df['c2']=["a1","a2","a2","a2","a1"]
df['c3']=[1,2,3,3,5]
print df
df1=df[df.duplicated()]
print df1
```

df1 has only one row, which is

```
    c1  c2  c3
3   3  a2   3
```

but I want to have

```
    c1  c2  c3
2   3  a2   3
3   3  a2   3
```

How to get it? One more thing, if I try to use argument 'keep' as `df1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]`, it gives me error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-572-188a22102b3e>", line 1, in <module>
 df1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

 File "C:\Users\Kanika\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: duplicated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the value that you specified for *keep* . I think, In your case Passing False as the keep value might solve the issue. [Pandas Duplicated Doc's](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) . Hope it helps.

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

this option delete all duplicates, defalult pandas keep first appear.