# python panda dataframe: argument 'keep' not working in drop_duplicates()/duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Suppose we have a dataframe `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['c1']=[1,2,3,3,4]
df['c2']=["a1","a2","a2","a2","a1"]
df['c3']=[1,2,3,3,5]
```

If I use either `df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)` or `df.duplicated(keep=False)`, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Kanika\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: duplicated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: separate out rows which have duplicates in panda dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154268/python-separate-out-rows-which-have-duplicates-in-panda-dataframe)

Comment: What version of pandas are you using as this works fine in version `0.18.0`

Comment: @ysearka it's not a duplicate, the OP is experiencing an error with calling those methods

Answer (score 2):

You should update your pandas version because it's added from `0.17.0` version, from [what's new in v. 0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#v0-17-0-october-9-2015):

> - `drop_duplicates` and `duplicated` now accept a `keep` keyword to target
>     first, last, and all duplicates.

Both works in pandas `0.18.1`:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]:
   c1  c2  c3
0   1  a1   1
1   2  a2   2
2   3  a2   3
3   3  a2   3
4   4  a1   5

In [117]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[117]:
   c1  c2  c3
0   1  a1   1
1   2  a2   2
2   3  a2   3
4   4  a1   5

In [118]: df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Out[118]:
   c1  c2  c3
0   1  a1   1
1   2  a2   2
4   4  a1   5
```